# Why is there 2 main threads running in ASP DLL?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, dll

When debugging a multi-threaded ASP DLL in Delphi 10 and 11.3, the debugger shows that 2 main threads are running at the same time.

It happens when the first main thread should have been terminated and another main thread is started in the same session.

This might be the cause of the problem being debugged.

Has anybody experienced this, and found a cause/fix for it?

Comment: Does your web app run inside an application pool in IIS? If yes, then read up what happens when the Application Pool is recycled. You might want to enable the "disallowOverlappingRotation" flag in the application pool if your app cannot have two workers at the same time.